# How can I use a variable to specify a COPY TO destination in a function?

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL 9.3, I want to create a function that copies data from a table into a CSV file.  This function works:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION backup_tables(character varying)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$

declare
     fileName text;
begin

    copy adhoc_query to 'c:/misc/adhoc_query.csv' csv;
    return 1;

end;
```

However, I get a syntax error from this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION backup_tables(character varying)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$

declare
    fileName text;
begin
    fileName = 'c:/misc/adhoc_query.csv';
    copy adhoc_query to fileName csv;
    return 1;

end;
```

pgAdmin flags "fileName" in the copy command as the location of the error.  I would like to be able to have the caller specify the destination file, but it looks to be impossible.  Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use anything else than a literal for the path. But you can build the command from the variables and then `EXECUTE` it.

```
...
EXECUTE 'COPY (' || adhoc_query || ') TO ''' || fileName || ''' CSV;';
...
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  I was hoping not to do this, but if I have to, I have to.

Answer (score 0):

Save your query in a .sql file and execute it with `psql` :

```bash
psql -U postgres -d database -A -F"," -f /path/to/sql/file.sql > /path/to/csv/file.csv
```

From the [psql doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html):

- **-A** : switches to unaligned output mode. (The default output mode is aligned.) This is equivalent to \pset format unaligned.
- **-F** : Use separator as the field separator for unaligned output. This is equivalent to \pset fieldsep or \f.